# How to create boot header for booting powerpc MPC8309twr with SD card

Tags: linux, boot-loader, sd-card, u-boot

I'm trying to boot the MPC8309twr with sd card. I found some documents AN3659_bf.pdf(describes the format for sd card boot header for MPC8536E) which uses a program called boot format. While formatting the sd card with boot format, we need to pass arguments as configuration file & bootloader image.Here I am having some doubts

a) How to build a RAM BASED u-boot Image, for building ram based u-boot what are the modifications need to be done in source code.

b) How to load the QE CODE, while bootloader is executing from NOR Flash it will load QE CODE with some predefined address in u-boot(ex:- fe7e0000) from flash. QE Code is necessary to load at executing at bootloader. so how can i load this QE CODE with sd card boot, for that in SD card where i need to copy this QE CODE.

with regards,

satish kumar.

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39011206/3541425)

Comment: You may ask this question to the manufacturer support or asking to a more appropriate forums like in NXP etc may help you out.